# API call results in System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have a method which obtains a list of employees from an API and then stores them in an ObservableCollection to be displayed on a ListView. I have had no luck however, as I keep getting this error "System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid".

I thought it was the list, but to my surprise even removing the assignment still crashed the app. What I found interesting as that **after** the API was completed and `var employees` was populated the code would jump back to the closing curly brace of the API call before returning the error stated. Any help is much appreciated. Please see my code below:

### ViewModel

```
public class EmployeeListViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private IUserService _userService { get; set; }
    public EmployeeListViewModel(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        GetEmployees();
    }

    private async void GetEmployees()
    {
        var employees = await _userService.GetEmployees();
        Employees = new MvxObservableCollection<User>(employees);
    }

    private MvxObservableCollection<User> _employees;
    public MvxObservableCollection<User> Employees
    {
        get => _employees;
        set { SetProperty(ref _employees, value); }
    }
}
```

### Service

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetEmployees()
{
    string url = $"{IpAddress}/{_controllerRoute}/getemployees";
    var content = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(url);
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(content);
}
```

### Model

```
public class User
//Simply copying IdentityUser, as this is the object being returned from the server
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string NormalizedUserName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual string NormalizedEmail { get; set; }
    public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string ConcurrencyStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? LockoutEnd { get; set; }
    public virtual bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please note that even though this is a reworded question, I have been advised by admins to reuse **deleted** questions to avoid getting banned from asking. Thanks for your patience and replies.

Comment: Which lines throws the exception and can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I'm not sure because it breaks at the close brace, it never stops at a line of code. But if this is any helpful, the blank screen that comes up with the error says `You app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).`

Comment: You made `EmployeeListViewModel.GetEmployees` an `async void`, apparently to be able to call it without `await` from the constructor. That is not going to work and I'm not surprised it crashes. See "What NOT to do" at https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html.

Comment: @GSerg Async voids aren’t that uncommon with MVVM where you have void events. But I do agree that this is very likely where the crash happens and due to not awaiting the call, there is no proper error reporting.

Comment: Can you verify that in `GetEmployees`, the `employees` does get properly set without any errors and that the data looks correct? In that case, the API side is not at fault and you can exclude that from being a possible reason where this fails. At that point, I would recommend you to swap the code that retrieves the data from a HTTP endpoint by some static data which you can use to test the remainder of your code.

Comment: @poke I can verify that the `var employees` is populated without a problem. That is an excellent suggestion (populating the property with hardcoded data). What I actually found was the error was still thrown! And then I commented it out... **no error!** Then I moved the initialisation of the `Employee` property to the constructor also with a hardcoded object and the error was still thrown. I can only point it to the `MvxObservableCollection` now. Am I right in saying so? And do you have a suggesstion on how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks so much everyone. I have just done a whoopsies. It's my fault, I examined my `XAML` and saw that I was using `<Label/>` instead of `<TextCell/>`. Thanks to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/60305/setting-itemssource-for-listview-defined-in-xaml-throws-invalidcastexception-at-runtime